# iPhone iOS 4 addTimeInterval deprecated

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, ios4

I'm using `addTimeInterval` for creating local notification but it seems that it is now deprecated (iOS 4).

My code:

```
localNotif.fireDate = [now addTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Xcode's warning:

```
'addTimeInterval:' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:27)
```

What should I use instead?
Thanks.

Comment: always read the release notes and api diff documentation

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The method has been renamed to [`-dateByAddingTimeInterval:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/dateByAddingTimeInterval:).

```
localNotif.fireDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

---

In Swift 2.2:

```
localNotif.fireDate = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
```

---

In Swift 3:

```
localNotif.fireDate = now.addingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
// or simply
localNotif.fireDate = now + timeInterval
```

Answer (score 11):

try that:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];     // current date
NSTimeInterval delta = 60 * 1;    // one minute later
if ([date respondsToSelector:@selector(dateByAddingTimeInterval:)]) {
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:delta];
}
else {
   date = [date addTimeInterval:delta];
}
```